# WordPress Pages, How to Upload Dynamic HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Ok, so I am just getting into programming, a little over a month so far.  I am starting with Javascript.  At the moment, **my goal is to get a small web application online** (instead of just opening the local files with browsers as I currently am).  I have my own domain name, a hosting service, and use Wordpress to blog.

I read codex.wordpress.org/Pages on Wordpress which seems to indicate I can include additional webpages on my Wordpress.  Unfortunately that, nor other articles, have not gotten me closer to my goal.

So here is some specific context about me and my work:

1. [Here](https://github.com/hallbd16/DynamicQuiz) is my git to my web application.  It is a dynamic quiz.
2. Dreamhost is my web hosting service and where I bought my domain through.
3. My wordpress site is www.briandavishall.com

I am stuck as to what my next steps should be, I really don't know where to start.  I would appreciate some guidance on what I should do, what I need to learn to accomplish my goal, and any resource recommendations if they exist.

Edit:
Here is what I did on my failed first attempt.

1.Added the following code to the `<head>` of the header.php file.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( "DynamicQuizJS" , plugins_url( ~/Documents/Coding/DynamicQuiz/DynamicQuizJS.js);); ?>
```

2.Linked/wrote this in the `<head>` of the page I wrote my HTML script.  As you can see [here](http://www.briandavishall.com/98-2/), nothing happens, there is no dynamic quiz :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="DynamicQuizJS.js"></script>
```

3.I am still unsure of how to do the CSS file.  I want it to be a separate file that I link the html script to as opposed to tinkering the existing CSS that I want the rest of my blog to follow.  I haven't spent enough time figuring this out yet, am doing so now. Update to come

**Update 2**

Embarrassingly, I still cannot accomplish my goal. I followed the suggested advice by Dave. I added the two lines of code to the theme I am using (the 2012 theme) with a link to the correct local address on my computer. I also used the same links in my html code that I added to a wordpress page via the text editor (not the visual editor).  See comments below for more detailsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if I understand correctly you want to add your custom app into your wordpress blog right?

Well, there are 3 parts to it.

1. Create the markup - HTML. Just add a new page/post in Wordpress and add your HTML markup into the editor: Make sure you switch to 'text', and not the default, which is 'visual'
2. Import your CSS - This is as easy as using the style editor inside wordpress: 
   `Appearance>Editor>Style.css` or you could just ass your css in the root directory, aka theme folder and then style.css
3. Javascript: Adding Javascript is just as easy. You could just include the  tags of your JS file into the header.php file of the theme. If you are having issues with that, read the following post:
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

**UPDATE:**

I think you are making this too complicated.

HTML:

Your html gets inserted into the Wordpress text editor(inside wordpress, under the blog page/post where you want your quiz displayed) - Make suer the tab is on "Text" and not "Visual".

CSS and JS:

Instead of adding your CSS to your Style.css file, you can just link BOTH your CSS and JS  files in the **header.php** file

Here is the header.php file for the twentytwelve theme: You can do the sam for your themes header.php file..
**See my code just above the closing head tag**

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>

/*The Only part I added:Below*/
/************Just add your files here below******************/
<link href="yourstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourJSfile.js"></script>

</head>
```

Just make sure your paths to your files are correct...

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but I must admit I am still having trouble.  Currently only the html is showing up, and the JS script and CSS are not linked.

Comment: Where did you put your JS/CSS? Your CSS should be put inside the style.css file. It can be found in the theme folder (what theme are you using?) or you can just find it under Appearance>Editor. Put your CSS code at the very bottom of the sheet. Your JS can be put in the header.php file of the theme folder. It will be in the root of the theme folder. I see that you are not using jQuery, so no need to wrap the JS in the jQuery tags...Just put in in script tags inside  the <head></head> of the header.php, better yet, the footer.php of the theme.

Comment: Dave, you rock for helping!  I left an update of what I have done as an edit above.  I guess my biggest question is, what syntax do I use to put the CSS/JS into the the style.css file/ header.php file?  And how do I call that in my html script code.

Comment: Embarrassingly, I still cannot accomplish my goal. I followed the suggested advice.  I added the two lines of code to the theme I am using (the 2012 theme) with a link to the correct local address on my computer.  I also used the same links in my html code that I added to a wordpress page via the text editor (not the visual editor).  The page that is created is [here](http://www.briandavishall.com/98-2/)    .  Perhaps you could take a look at the exact code I wrote.  It is in this [git repository](https://github.com/hallbd16/myWordPress_Application)

Comment: Problem solved.  Needed to host js file on server before linking.  I was linking to the local address.

Comment: yup...sometimes you just need to look for the obvious first - remember the best answer to a solutions is usually the easiest one. Thank you for the rep